# how to add recommended products on product page magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am modifying my product  page and I have to add a side div to add recommended products like this 
[image: Recommended products on right bottom of product page]. And my code of

> `app/design/frontend/infornite/base/magento_catalog/layout/Catalog_Product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- 
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> 
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceContainer name="content" >
            <block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-">
                <container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" />
                <container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" />
                <container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" />
                <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" />

                <!-- Static blocks -->
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <!-- Reset attributes of main containers -->
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" before="-" />
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.media" htmlTag="" htmlClass="" after="product.info.main" />

        <!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper -->
        <move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" />

        <!-- Move some blocks to new positions -->
        <!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> -->
        <!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> -->
        <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
        <move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" after="page.main.title" />
        <move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" />

        <!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file -->
        <move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper" />

        <!-- Product collateral data (tabs) -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details" template="Infortis_Base::product/view/details.phtml" >
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_tabs" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::showTabs" />
            </arguments>
            <!-- Custom static blocks as tabs -->
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block1" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab1</argument>
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle">
                        <param name="id">block_product_tab1</param>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="product_cms_block2" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_tab2</argument>
                    <argument name="title" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getStaticBlockTitle">
                        <param name="id">block_product_tab2</param>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="catalog.product.related">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getRelatedProductsTemplate" />
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" >
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="helper" helper="Infortis\Base\Helper\Template\Catalog\Product\View::getUpsellProductsTemplate" />
                <!-- TODO: -->
                <argument name="is_responsive" xsi:type="string">false</argument>
                <argument name="show_items" xsi:type="string">3</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.crosssell">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Infortis_Base::product/list/slider.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

  <move element="reviews.tab" destination="main.content" after="-"/> 
  <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product.info.main" before="-"/> 
    </body>
</page>
```

How I can add this widget as its not in pages which is on back-end. Any help would be highly appreciated . Thank you

Comment: don't put magento 1.9 tag if you are using magento 2

Comment: okay @ManojDeswal . I need small help if you are free ?

Comment: sure I ll help whatever possible

Comment: can you come in chat section please ? @ManojDeswal

Comment: let me know your problem , I don't any chat option here , once comes I ll come

Comment: @ManojDeswal  I am able to show now related products on desired place but products are coming in slider form . I want to show only 2 products all time which are recommended not related . Is there any soloution ?

Comment: I ll check and will post solution if I got ... you need related items should show only 2 items ... and no slider should removed ... related items text you can change to recommended items

Comment: @ManojDeswal  exactly same . And We discuss that day in chat you showed me a button to appear popup for review. If you have solution for that ?

Comment: that is customize by developer and used bootstrap ...so if you are using bootstrap in theme then that can work .. as same as i sent you a site link

Comment: @ManojDeswal how can I add button on product page ?  I have review form already made. So just want to show button and then onclick to appear that form .

Comment: actually I made that will help of bootstrap ... because I am not a JS writer ... with bootstrap classes I done that

Comment: @ManojDeswal I was just asking a rough idea how to make a button on a page .

Comment: just give some styles , and add onClick action ..modal popup...just write some js code ...and call your form in that modal block with help of js

Comment: thank you I will try @ManojDeswal . And if you get any solution of problem describe above kindly let me know . It would be great favor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65885/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-learner).

Comment: @ManojDeswal bro I need few minutes you there ?